# Windows Azure VM Replication Health Critical

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, azure, replication

In the Windows Azure Portal, the Replication for some of our VMs are showing that the replication health for them is critical. However, the status of them is protected and the they are crash-consistent and app-consistent with today's date.

They are also showing in Hyper-V as having a replication health of normal, replica server is Microsoft Azure.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Screenshots:

[image: Azure Portal]

[image: HyperV view]

Comment: open a ticket with Microsoft.

Comment: Could you please show me the screenshot about it?

Comment: Edited the original post to include screenshots.